# Text File Reading and Printing Data

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

**My Text File MyText.txt**

```
This is line 1
This is line 2 
Time Taken for writing this#      0 days 0 hrs 1 min 5 sec
Nothing Important
Sample Text
```

**Objective**

To read the text file and find if "Sample Test is present in the file. If present print the time taken to write the file(which is a value already inside the file)"

**My Code**

```
with open('MyText.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
            f.seek(0)
            f.readline()
            for line in f:
                if 'Time Taken' in line:
                    print line
                    print ' '.join(line.split())
f.close()
```

The code is working fine. My question is if this code can be made even better . Considering I am new to python, I am sure there would be a better way to code this.Can anyone sugggest alternative/faster approach for this.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work..

```
with open('MyText.txt', 'r') as f:
  lineArr=f.read().split('\n')
  if 'Sample Text' in lineArr:
    timeTaken = [s for s in lineArr if "Time Taken" in s]
    print timeTaken[0]
```

Comment: Mate this prints `['Time Taken for writing this#      0 days 0 hrs 1 min 5 sec']`

Comment: @misguided- Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I wanted the resultant file name rather than list . Your changed code is helpful though :)

Answer (score 4):

```
f = open('sample', 'r') # open file in read mode
data = f.read()      # copy to a string
f.close()               # close the file
print data          # print the data
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd get the text out, and then perform operations on it, if the file is fairly small.

```
f = open("mytext.txt","r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()

for row in contents.split("\n"):
    if "time" in row:
        print(row.split("time")[1])
```

Comment: Mate you have considered only 1 condition , not 2