# Text File Reading and Structuring data

Tags: python, parsing

## Text File

```
• I.D.: AN000015544 
DESCRIPTION: 6 1/2 DIGIT DIGITAL MULTIMETER 
MANUFACTURER: HEWLETT-PACKARDMODEL NUM.: 34401A CALIBRATION - DUE DATE:6/1/2016 SERIAL NUMBER: MY45027398 
• I.D.: AN000016955 
DESCRIPTION: TEMPERATURE CALIBRATOR 
MANUFACTURER: FLUKE MODEL NUM.: 724 CALIBRATION - DUE DATE:6/1/2016 SERIAL NUMBER: 1189063 
• I.D.: AN000017259 
DESCRIPTION: TRUE RMS MULTIMETER 
MANUFACTURER: AGILENT MODEL NUM.: U1253A CALIBRATION - DUE DATE:6/1/2016 SERIAL NUMBER: MY49420076
```

## Objective

To read the text file and save the ID number and Serial number of each part into the part_data data structure.

## Data Structure

```
part_data = {'ID': [],
               'Serial Number': []}
```

## Code

```
with open("textfile", 'r') as part_info:
    lineArray = part_info.read().split('\n')
    print(lineArray)
    if "• I.D.: AN000015544 " in lineArray:
        print("I have found the first line")
        ID = [s for s in lineArray if "AN" in s]
        print(ID[0])
```

My code isn't finding the I.D: or the serial number value. I know it is wrong I was trying to use the method I got from this website [Text File Reading and Printing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440815/python-text-file-reading-and-printing-data) for parsing the data. Can anyone move me in the right direction for collecting the values?

## Update

This solution works with python 2.7.9 not 3.4, thanks to domino -  https://stackoverflow.com/users/209361/domino:

```
with open("textfile", 'r') as part_info:
lineArray = part_info.readlines()
for line in lineArray:
    if "I.D.:" in line:
        ID = line.split(':')[1]
        print ID.strip()
```

However when I initially asked the question I was using python 3.4, and the solution did not work properly.

Does anyone understand why it doesn't work python 3.4? Thank You!

Comment: should there be space after ID number?

Comment: Try adding `lineArray = [l.strip() for l in lineArray]` and then searching for the  string you were, but without the space. You might have some `\r`s or other hidden whitespace in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print out all your ID's. I think it should move you in the right direction.

```
with open("textfile", 'r') as part_info:
    lineArray = part_info.readlines()
    for line in lineArray:
        if "I.D.:" in line:
            ID = line.split(':')[1]
            print ID.strip()
```

Comment: For some reason when I search the text for I.D.: it can't seem to find it in the line. Did it work for you?

Comment: I think the text file has a different encoding or something like that?

Comment: Works for me. I just copied what you pasted into a text file and it worked. No special encoding.

Comment: It works just had to switch python interpreter to 2.7

Answer (score 1):

It won't work in python3 because in python3 print is a function

It should end

```
print(ID.strip())
```